# Python insert a line just above the second occurrence of a pattern from end of file

Tags: python

I have a RHEL kickstart file as below with multiple **%post ... %end** sections in it having many lines of Python code in between them.

```
%post
.....
.....
%end
%post
.....
.....
%end
%post
.....
.....
%end
```

I am trying to insert a new line with some data just before (above) the 2nd occurrence of search pattern "**%end**" from last (EOF). Any hints/input is really appreciated.

Comment: how about Unix command-line tools?

Comment: @don_crissti I tried with findall() but gives list of the patterns from that I have used -2 index to retrieve the 2nd occurrence of pattern from last, but unable to fetch the line no above this 2nd occurrence of the pattern

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I used the code something like, `tac file | awk -v n=0 '/%end/ {n++}; if (n==3) {print FNR-1}'`

Comment: What's the relevance of Python in the title?

Comment: @roaima I have to do it via Python to insert some python code into this target kickstart file which contains python code. I am thinking of using shell script is to be imbibed in Python's `subprocess.Popen()`

Comment: So does the code you want need to be written in Python? If so, please say so in your question. If not, then remove the misleading reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python snippet that inserts text `spam` at the last position in the second-to-last `%post..%end` block:

```
with open('input') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

locs = [i for i, val in enumerate(lines) if val == '%end\n']
lines.insert(locs[-2], 'spam' + '\n')

with open('input', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(''.join(lines))
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert *"some data"* before next to last pattern line.
**`grep`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v n="$(($(grep -c '^%end' inputfile) - 1))" \
'/^%end/{ if (++cnt == n) print "some data" }1' inputfile
```

The output:

```
%post
.....
.....
%end
%post
.....
.....
some data
%end
%post
.....
.....
%end
```